# d3 Directed Graph Editor additions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I have been trying to augment the [d3 Directed Graph Editor code](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) with a couple of ideas which would make it a very intuitive interface for people wanting to "manually grow" a graph. I managed to change the node ids to strings which the user can enter through a prompt call. The same goes for adding a "type" value to the links connecting the nodes.

The part I struggling with is that I can't manage to get the link property "type" rendered in the middle of the link when the graph redraws. Can anybody offer help/the code I would be able to manage doing so?

Here are the lines which set up example nodes and links:

```
var nodes = [
    {id: 'some name', reflexive: false},
    {id: 'some other name', reflexive: true },
    {id: 'some 3rd name', reflexive: false}
],
links = [
    {source: nodes[0], target: nodes[1], left: false, right: true ,type: 'some type I'},
    {source: nodes[1], target: nodes[2], left: false, right: true, type: 'some type II'}
];
```

When the nodes get rendered there is a code which adds the id as a string:

```
g.append('svg:text')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 4)
    .attr('class', 'id')
    .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
```

However when the links get redrawn there is no function which get's the value of the type property and parses it 1/2 way between the coordinates of the source and target nodes. Here is the code which deals, as far as I can tell with rendering the links.

```
// update existing links
path.classed('selected', function(d) { return d === selected_link; })
    .style('marker-start', function(d) { return d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : ''; })
    .style('marker-end', function(d) { return d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : ''; });


// add new links
path.enter().append('svg:path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .classed('selected', function(d) { return d === selected_link; })
    .style('marker-start', function(d) { return d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : ''; })
    .style('marker-end', function(d) { return d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : ''; })
    .on('mousedown', function(d) {
        if(d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

        // select link
        mousedown_link = d;
        if(mousedown_link === selected_link) selected_link = null;
        else selected_link = mousedown_link;
        selected_node = null;
        restart();
    });
```

Here is a [link to a jsfiddle with the latest version of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/rco31ofe/1/).

Comment: Can we so your problems in code within question?

Comment: For this sort of question it would be worth posting over on [d3.js google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/d3-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your tick function just recalculate the xy position of your text based on source and target xy:

```
 function tick() {
   d3.selectAll("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) {return (d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2})
   .attr("y", function(d) {return (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2})
 }
```

Here's an updated jsFiddle with path labels:
http://jsfiddle.net/rco31ofe/2/

Comment: I added the code and it breaks the script. Also while it may generate the correct position for the label I am still stuck with how to put the string at the new location.

Comment: That code will put any text created with edge data at the center point of a straight line drawn from source to target and will adjust it with the network. If you put an interactive version up on bl.ocks or jsFiddle, we can see what's wrong. The code I put in there should be inside your tick function, which may not be named tick() of course.

Comment: Hi Elija. Thanks for trying to help out a d3 noob. I added a link to a jsfiddle to the question.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I don't have enough reputation yet to vote up the answer but I'll do so when I have 15. :-)

Comment: any idea why this doesn't work in IE11? The links don't show up correctly and if you add some more they leave garbage behind as you pan the nodes. Seems other force layout examples like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292 have the same issue. The author of the original graph editor sample told me "it appears that IE doesn't properly support programmatically updating inline SVG elements" and that a workaround I was thinking of, that is removing and reading links at tick, will probably be inefficient. Any other ideas for workarounds?